# How to remove left margin from DIV when below 767px width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple one for someone here. I have a div that uses the bootstrap columns :

```
<div class="current-plan col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
</div>
```

The CSS for current-plan :

```
.current-plan{
   margin-left: 5%;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #000;
   height: 150px;
}
```

I want the 5% margin left to disappear when the screen goes below 767px width.

I've tried using `@media` queries but it doesn't seem to be interacting with it.

The div is also nested inside of Bootstraps container div :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="current-plan col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you tried a media query and it didn't work, you probably don't have enough specificity. Try adding `!important` to the declaration.

Comment: Tried the !important thing, but no success :(

Comment: You'll need to post more code. Maybe a demo. Something is apparently overriding your newer code, but we can't tell from the limited info in your question.

Comment: It's hosted on my local machine, so I can't give you a demo. I'm unsure of what code you need to see.

Comment: For a demo you can use jsfiddle.net and post the link in your question, otherwise post enough code in your question that allows us to replicate the problem you're having.

Comment: @Michael_B: would the content inside current-plan effect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `!important` declaration :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .current-plan{
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    }
}
```

You can also use Javascript by adding this inside your `<body>`:

```
<script>
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 766px)" );
if (mq.matches) {
   var el = document.getElementsByClassName("current-plan");
   for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      elems[i].style.marginLeft = "0px";
   }
}
</script>
```

Or edit styles directly in Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Tried this as well, but no luck!

Comment: Can you right click on the `.current-plan` section in the browser an choose *Inspect Element* to see what it gives? Is the style rules written in CSS, HTML or in Javascript? Are you sure it's `.current-plan`?

Comment: It's definitely current-plan, I have unchecked the margin-left property in the dev tools and it looks perfect, so I know it's the margin and I'm looking at the correct class. It's written purely in CSS.

Comment: Have you tried the Javascript solution in my anwer's edit?

Comment: Yes, doesn't seem to work. I'm using a html template page, so it doesn't have the normal <html><head> tags, it's just content.

Comment: When you inspect the margin-left property in the dev tools, do you find `!important` declaration? If you do, follow the path and the line in where the rule is written and delete `!important` directly from bootstrap file. The path and the line number are shown above the margin-left property in dev tools.

Comment: I found the issue, some CSS code that I copied from the internet was missing a semi-colon right above the media query...

Answer (score 0):

Add more selectors to current-plan:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .container .current-plan {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried these, but as stated, it's not interacting.

Comment: Add more selectors to current-plan - .container .current-plan {}